# ubuntu python selenium PhantomJS load failed

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, phantomjs

it run correctly in windows but failed in ubuntu16.04

it run correctly in chrome but failed in PhantomJS

only load 'https://www.facebook.com/' failed

here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
service_args = ['--proxy=localhost:1081', '--proxy-type=socks5', ]
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
browser.get('https://twitter.com/')
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('twitter.png')
browser.get('http://www.facebook.com/')
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('facebook.png')
browser.quit()
```

here is the result:[facebook load failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAqxO.png)

but twitter load success

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly i try to use phantomjs 2.1.1, then i get this error,when i try to use phantomjs 2.1.0 the error still have,finally i use phantomjs 1.9.8,and now,fortunately,everything  is ok .I think maybe this is a bug phantomjs 2 with ubuntu.